# Rogue layer printing to GeoPDF in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pdf, printing, geospatial-pdf

I have a plan, in QGIS version 3.22.16, with two layer groups and am using them to supply maps to two different pages in a layout file controlled by map themes. I am printing one page at a time by excluding the other page and map from exports. Somehow one rogue layer from page 2, map 2 is jumping themes and printing with page 1, map 1. The layer has no content when it does this but all the same I would prefer  to not have the confusion of an extra layer listed that is not associated.

I tried recreating a new layer to replace the rogue one and deleting the rogue one and the replacement layer showed up in the same place.

As noted by J.R. in the comments below I believe that I had the "GPS Tie Ins" layer turned off in the GeoPDF export options yet it still came through as a listed but blank layer.  See screen shots of QGIS and Adobe Reader Layers.

[image]
[image]

I was a bit impatient when replacing the layer did not work so rather than deleting the layer I created a separate layout file for each page and was able to print what I needed that way.

This seems like a bug to me but if I have made an obvious error in the process please let me know for next time.  Thanks to All.

Comment: Welcome to our community!
Could you maybe provide some screenshots as an example so as to make it easier to understand the question with real-world data?

Comment: When you export with option to create GeospatialPDF you may select witch layer are visible and witch attribute to include, maybe changing this setting could solve your problem

Comment: Please see revisions above.  Thanks.